# how to track click,open mails using mailgun and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mailgun

Could anyone tell me how to track mails by using mailgun api with nodejs?

I am trying to send and track mail for my personal use. I got the below example from tutorials and working fine. Now I want to track the opened/click mails.

serv.js

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
        var api_key = 'mykey';
        var domain = 'mydomain.in';
        var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

        var mailgun = new Mailgun({ apiKey: api_key, domain: domain });
        var data = {
            from: "hello@hello.com",
            to: "hi@hi.com",            
            subject: req.body.subject, 
            text: req.body.plaintext,
            'o:tag': req.body.tag,
           // 'o:tracking-clicks':req.body.trackingclicks,
            //'o:tracking-opens':req.body.trackingopens
        };
        console.log(req.body);
        mailgun.messages().send(data, function(error, body) {
            console.log(body);
            //Email not sent
            if (error) {
                res.render('index', { title: 'No Email', msg: 'faild', err: true })
            }
            //Yay!! Email sent
            else {
                res.render('index', { title: success.', err: false })
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You will no be able to track mail that is opened reliably, unless you embed an external image in the email's HTML and log on the server when it is downloaded, but people may still block external resources for getting downloaded for exactly that reason that they don't want to be tracked. Spammers use such techniques to track which email accounts are worth spamming so it became an issue.

For tracking the clicking of some link or button in the email, you need to make an endpoint on your backend to track the clicks on those links and integrate it with the sending of emails - to know which link is from which email. This shouldn't be blocked by email clients because it is their explicit action of clicking that link but some people may stil choose to not click any links in emails for security reasons.

Comment: that's really great answer. i was to blind about how to work with some api integration and tracking. now theoretically am cleared. thanks for your response :) could you pls share tutorial regarding this. just want to understand logically how it works.